# django-bootstrap3 Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using django-bootstrap3 to render my forms on the template and i have been struggling to find what is causing the error `Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField` when i try to load the page with the form on it. I have attached my code and error below. can someone please point for me what i'm doing wrong?

forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms. EmailField(max_length=50)
    institution_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    problem = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs—Crows':10,'cols':18,'style':'resize:none',  [placeholder':'Please define your problem here'l),label='Problem description')
    [placeholder':'Please define your problem here'l),label='Problem description')
```

views.py

```
def Orderview(request):
    if request.method == 'Post':
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
```

`if order_form.is_valid():
        cd = order form.cleaned data


        subject = '{} repair order from {}'.format(cd['item'],cd['institution_name']) 

        from_email = cd['email']

        to = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,]

        ctx = {
  'first_name':cd['first_name'],
  'last_name':cd['last_name'], 
  'email':cd['email'],
  'institution_name':cd['institution_name'],
  'phone':cd['phone'],
  'address':cd['address'], 
  'city':cd['city'],
  'item':cd['item'],
  'serial_number.:cd['serial_number'],
  'problem':cd['problem'],

               }

          message = get_template('electroapp/email/order.html').render(Context(ctx)) 
          msg = EmailMessage(subject,message,to=to,from_email=from_email) 
          msg.content_subtype='html'
          msg.send()

          messages.success(request,' Your Repair order has been sent',) 

          return redirect('electroapp:repair_order')



  else:
      order_form = OrderForm() 

  return render(request,'electroapp/orderform.html',{'Order_form':order_form})`

template
[image: template file]

browser error
[image]

console logs
[image: console error logs]

Comment: post the error log in your terminal may help

Comment: i have edited the question and added the error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because some fields may be missing.Take a look at [this](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/issues/296)

You could do something like this to see what fields are available:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% bootstrap_form order_form %}
     {% buttons submit='OK' reset="Cancel" %}{% endbuttons %}
 </form>
```

and then try to figure out why you are having missing fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField**

Why can't they just tell us which actual field?  Well, here's how I solved it.

A little debugging and you'll find this is thrown within renderers.py:

```
class FieldRenderer(BaseRenderer):
"""Default field renderer."""

# These widgets will not be wrapped in a form-control class
WIDGETS_NO_FORM_CONTROL = (CheckboxInput, RadioSelect, CheckboxSelectMultiple, FileInput)

def __init__(self, field, *args, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(field, BoundField):
        raise BootstrapError('Parameter "field" should contain a valid Django BoundField.')
    self.field = field
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) ...
```

The message is not helpful, but can be fixed in your dev/test environment.

WARNING: The following will void your warranty! :)

Go up a few steps in the render chain in library.py  (for example ~/.virtualenvs/your_env/lib/python3.8/site/packages/django/template/library.py)
and find SimpleNode.

```
class SimpleNode(TagHelperNode):

def __init__(self, func, takes_context, args, kwargs, target_var):
    super().__init__(func, takes_context, args, kwargs)
    self.target_var = target_var

def render(self, context):
    resolved_args, resolved_kwargs = self.get_resolved_arguments(context)
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
    if self.target_var is not None:
        context[self.target_var] = output
        return ''
    if context.autoescape:
        output = conditional_escape(output)
    return output
```

After copying the original file to a backup, change it as follows.  We are wrapping the line

> output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

with a try/except.  Here's the result:

```
class SimpleNode(TagHelperNode):

def __init__(self, func, takes_context, args, kwargs, target_var):
    super().__init__(func, takes_context, args, kwargs)
    self.target_var = target_var

def render(self, context):
    resolved_args, resolved_kwargs = self.get_resolved_arguments(context)
###
    from bootstrap3.exceptions import BootstrapError
    try:
        output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
    except BootstrapError as b:
        raise BootstrapError(str(b).replace('"field"', self.args[0].token)) from b
###
    if self.target_var is not None:
        context[self.target_var] = output
        return ''
    if context.autoescape:
        output = conditional_escape(output)
    return output
```

Within the SimpleNode class we have access to the name of the field that couldn't be rendered.  So we intercept the exception there and re-throw it with the useful tidbit injected.  Voila, you will now get an exception report that tells you the *actual problem field*.
Cheers.